# How to pass a variable to sql in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am reading a text file in the begining an trying to pass the values to the select statement after that in the shell script and I am getting the below error:            ERROR at line 13:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
end of the file
Reading the text file is working separately and select statement is working separately. Can someone help?

Comment: It would help us if you edited your questions and pasted the excerpts of the code that you are working on.

Comment: Paste code snippets please

Comment: This sounds like an incorrectly escaped string.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh
IFS='|'
 
# file name
file=/backup/diskonly_backupfiles/EMPTORIS_ACE/LATEST/Batch1/contract.txt
 

while read contract dmsuuid
do
 print "$contract has contract $dmsuuid"
 echo contract $contract
 echo dmsuuid $dmsuuid
var1=`sqlplus -s xxx/yyy@zzz <<END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
SELECT atch.FILENAME
  FROM attachment atch
 WHERE contract_number = $contract and dmsuuid = $dmsuuid;
exit;
END`

echo var1 $var1
echo end of the file
done <"$file" This is not working. Can someone help?